# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

**What I am trying to do:** Starting from a Master/Detail flow project, I am trying to enable the user to press an item in the ActionMenu which should show a fragment where new data can be put in.

**Problem:** I get an error when I try to start the fragment. What am I doing wrong?

After pasting the code I think I have made a mess of it. Still need help.

**Error:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090040 (com.example.androidtest:id/AddItem_fragment) for fragment AddItem{5b161e7 #1 id=0x7f090040}

**ItemListActivity.java:**

```
public class ItemListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ItemListFragment.Callbacks {

private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_actions, menu);
    setTitle("Shoppinglistan");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            openAddItem();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_send:
            //openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();            

    } else {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}

public void openAddItem() {
    AddItem additem = new AddItem();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.AddItem_fragment, additem).commit();
}

public static class AddItem extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additem_layout,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

**activity_item_detail.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.androidtest.ItemDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment 
    android:name="com.example.androidtest.AddItem"
    android:id="@+id/AddItem_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" 

    />

</FrameLayout>
```

**additem_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you think by _Actionmenu_? Do you mean [Action overflow](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)?

Comment: Where is your fragment container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is this line

```
public void openAddItem() {
AddItem additem = new AddItem();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.AddItem_fragment, additem).commit();
}
```

you already have it here

```
 <fragment 
android:name="com.example.androidtest.AddItem"
android:id="@+id/AddItem_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp" 
/>
```

you can not recreate it programmatically, all you need to do is remove the programmatically added fragment,and this will be there, since (in a different language its stack)..

**EDIT**

to address your comment,first of all add a tag to your fragments when calling `ItemDetailFragment` for instance `"ItemDetailFragment"` & instead of the previous code in `openAddItem()` replace them with this

```
public void openAddItem() {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().
       findFragmentByTag("ItemDetailFragment"));
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(); // 
// if your fragment is still not showing then uncomment the below line
//getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(getSupportFragmentManager().
     findFragmentById(the_id_of_ur_fragment));
}
```

hope its good enough

Comment: I tried removing the code above like you said and the exception is gone but nothing happens when I press my button (to trigger the opening of the fragment). Perhaps I messed up something else?

Comment: check my edit Sir, dont forget to upvote if it helped you and accept if it solved **all** your problems @riki-oh

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the add method:

> abstract FragmentTransaction  add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
>
> Calls add(int, Fragment, String) with a null tag.

In your code:

```
public void openAddItem() {
    AddItem additem = new AddItem();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.AddItem_fragment, additem).commit();
}
```

This code will find in your views a view with the id `R.id.AddItem_frament` and it will try to attach to it the view associated to the fragment passed. Since in your layout there is not a `ViewGroup` that serves as a container it is launching you a legitimate `IllegalArgumentException` since the id is not present. What you have to do is provide a container in which you can add all the fragments and passing to the add method of the transaction this id.

Comment: By 'providing a container' do you mean like creating a RelativeLayout in the fragment.xml?

Comment: I mean providing a ViewGroup, which can be any RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout... with the id AddItem_fragment